# How do I make the leaderboard not reset after restarting my client

Tags: typescript, discord, leaderboard

How do I make the leaderboard not reset after restarting my client, here is an example:[image]

**ignore the "undefined" right there, I'll fix it**

Here the leaderboard is only showing the people who've used the bot after it restarted, and when they use a command, they'll pop up on the leaderboard as shown below:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    let Data = await UserModel.find({});
    let Members = [];
    for (let obj of Data) {
      if (
        message.guild?.members.cache.map((member) => member.id).includes(obj.ID)
      )
        Members.push(obj);
    }
    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.guild?.name}'s Leaderboard`)
      .setFooter({
        text: `You aren't ranked yet!`,
        iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
      });
    Members = Members.sort(function (b, a) {
      return a.Money - b.Money;
    });
    Members = Members.filter(function BigEnough(value) {
      return value.Money > 0;
    });
    let pos = 0;
    for (let obj of Members) {
      pos++;
      if (obj.ID === message.author.id) {
        Embed.setFooter({
          text: `You are ranked ${pos} in the leaderboard!`,
          iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
        });
      }
    }

    Members = Members.slice(0, 10);
    let desc: any;
    for (let i = 0; i < Members.length; i++) {
      let User = message.guild?.members.cache.get(Members[i].ID);
      if (!User) return;
      let Bal = Members[i].Money;
      desc += `${i + 1}. ${User.user.tag} - $${Math.round(Bal)}\n`;
    }
    Embed.setDescription(desc);
    Embed.setColor("RED");
    message.reply({ embeds: [Embed] });
```

It's is basically just showing the cached users, is there a way to get all the users in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch all the members of the guild first. Fetching the guild will add all the members to the cache.

Using for instance: [guild.members.fetch();](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) or by changing your client default caching option.

```js
message.guild.members.fetch(members => {
  let membersArray = members.array();
  for(var guildMemberId in membersArray) {
    let member = membersArray[guildMemberId];
    //Loop here with your member.
  }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't quite use this to fix my code at the moment. Can you make this piece of code use `fetch()`?

`message.guild?.members.cache.map((member) => member.id).includes(obj.ID)`

Comment: Make sure to await for the async fetch to complete. Can't really help you, I'm not familiar with typescript.
Something like: message.guild?.members.fetch().then(members => { 
doYourStuff()
});